# Can I use transform:scale() inside a <div> tag?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I've been trying to use this code snippet:

```html
<div style="transform:scale(2,0)"><p>Hello World</p></div>
```

But the div doesn't change its size. Am I doing something wrong? Or is it that I can't use the `transform:scale()` inside the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 issues. First you are using `0` value in the second argument which means that you are scaling your element to `0` height thus its invisible.

If we correct this and we make it `1` you need to consider **the origin** of the scale which is the center of your element by default, so scaling twice will make the text to disappear on the left of the screen.

Add an animation and you will clearly notice this:

```css
.change {
 animation:change 2s linear infinite alternate;
 border:1px solid;
 /*the center*/
 background:linear-gradient(red,red) center/10px 100% no-repeat;
}
@keyframes change{
  to{transform:scale(2,1);}
}
```

```html
<div class="change"><p>Hello World</p></div>
```

You need to adjust the `transform-origin` and you will be able to see the element

```html
<div style="transform:scale(2,1);transform-origin:left;"><p>Hello World</p></div>
```